# Coded UI - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

Whenever i try to record an action in a coded UI test , the action is recorded but as soon as i try to generate the code an error pops up saying 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
The recording was working fine till yesterday so there is no issue of visual studio version or service pack. I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate.

Comment: are you still running into this issue?

Comment: it got solved.. restored my computer to a previous checkpoint and it started working.